# How do I disable touch events in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, touch

I have a JavaFX application which has issues with Windows 8 touch events. For some reason, I get a crash when the user touches in the application window in certain situations. I'd like to completely disable touch events and revert instead to regular left-clicking (I don't use any fancy gestures).

How can I tell JavaFX to handle touch events as regular mouse clicks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful to know what kind of crash you are seeing (stack trace or dump, java version, etc) since touch events should work fine in Java 8. As for your event redirect question you might want to try this:

Add a TouchEvent.ANY EventFilter in the topmost node (your primary stage for example) and consume it (this will consume all touch events before bubbling down to its target), after consuming you can forward the event as a new MouseEvent (say MouseClick). See this sample:

```
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.TouchEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.TouchPoint;


primaryStage.addEventFilter(TouchEvent.ANY, new EventHandler<TouchEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(TouchEvent event) {
                // Consume the touch event
                event.consume();

                // Create a fake MouseEvent (MOUSE_CLICKED) for the current touch event
                TouchPoint touchPoint = event.getTouchPoint();
                int clickCount = 1;
                MouseEvent mouseEvent = new MouseEvent(event.getSource(), event.getTarget(),
                        MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, touchPoint.getX(), touchPoint.getY(), touchPoint
                                .getScreenX(), touchPoint.getScreenY(), MouseButton.PRIMARY,
                        clickCount, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, true, false,
                        false, null);

                // Fire the fake event
                Scene yourScene = primaryStage.getScene();
                Event.fireEvent(yourScene.getRoot(), mouseEvent);
            }
});
```

You might want to add some extra checks/logic to the code to be able to send different MouseEvents based in the TouchEvent type. However, I would recommend trying to find the root cause of your current crash before trying something like this.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I actually did find the root cause of the crash and it somehow seemed to be completely unrelated, but it fixed the crash. Also, I couldn't post any errors because there were none, the whole jvm crashed. Thank you for your answer, it's much appreciated.

Comment: I'm glad you fixed your crash! This FX event redirect will surely help you (or someone else) in the future.. I has proven to be invaluable for me to redirect some events from Swing to FX.